# Find_by_slug with Mongoid method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

I am using Mongoid(3.0.23) and I want to add nicer URL's, I have followed [this rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised) but for some reason my site throws an undefined error for the `find_by_slug` method. I have read about some gems I could use but it seems pointless for such a simple task.

### Model

```
validates :slug, :uniqueness => true

before_validation :generate_url

def generate_url
  self.slug ||= self.title.parameterize if slug.blank?
end 

def to_param
  slug
end

field :slug
```

### View

```
<% @events.each do |e|  %>
  <%= link_to e.title, event_path(e) %>  
<% end %>
```

### Controller

```
def show
   @event = Event.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
Event.find_by(slug: params[:id])
```

Also, not sure if it's necessary but you could specify the type:

```
 field :slug, type: String
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid defines the attribute finder, but not the bang version.

```
Event.find_by_slug(params[:id])
# => valid
Event.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
# => not defined
```

In any case, given the way ActiveModel is taking and according to best practices, it's better for you define all the public API of your model.

```
class Event
  def self.find_by_slug!(slug)
    where(slug: slug).first || raise(Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound, self, slug: slug)
  end
end
```

You can also re-use find_by_slug, but as I said, because ActiveRecord is deprecating find_by_attribute, I prefer to write the code directly.

Comment: This worked for me - find_by(slug: params[:id]). Much simpler :)